# Jquery validation error displayed on "label". How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My form is made using the “bootstrap” styles. To check for input fields, I use “jquery” validation. Label with the name is on top of input, when you click on input, “label” moves over “input”. When you click “Next”, the error “validation” appears on top of the “label” with the name, and should be located under the “input”. How to fix so that “label” moves above “input” and the error is below “input”?
[my code](https://codepen.io/Smith37/pen/abOOLNZ)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</script>
 <style type="text/css">
  #step2,#step3,#step4,#step5{
        display: none;
       }

       .form-group label
      {
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        pointer-events: none;
        left: 20px;
        transition: .5s;
      }
       .container .form-group input:focus ~label,
       .container .form-group input:valid ~label
      {
        left: 20px;
        top: -20px;
        color: rgb(66,133,244);
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

  </style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
$.validator.addMethod("minlenghtname", function (value, element) {
        return /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
    }," does not match the format");

$.validator.addMethod("requiredname", function (value, element) {
        return value.length > 2;
    }," fill this field");

 var v = $("#commentForm").validate({
        rules: {
            fname: {
                requiredname: true,
                minlenghtname: true
            },
            lname: {
                requiredname: true,
                minlenghtname: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
                alert("Submitted, thanks!");
            }

    })

    $(".next1").click(function() {
            if (v.form()) {
                $("#step2").show();
                $("#step1").hide();
                $("#progressText").html("Step 2 of 4");

            }
      });

});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="progressText" style="margin-bottom:20px;">Step 1 of 4</div>
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
<div id="step1">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
       <input class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" required="">
       <label>First Name:</label>
       </div>  
       <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" required="">
        <label>Last Name:</label>
       </div>
        <p class="buttonWrapper">
        <input name="formNext1" type="button" class="next1 nextbutton" value="Next" alt="Next" title="Next">
            </p>
 </div>
</div>    
  <div id="step2">
    Next
  </div>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Validation also uses labels to show errors so you end up with double label for each field. Those from validation come with `error` class, so you can target them and either show it normally:

```
.form-group label.error {
  position: static;
}
```

or treat it like that label but move down:

```
.form-group label.error {
  top: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Everything turned out to be much simpler. At the label indicate the class and refer to it.

.form-group label.name
      {
        position: absolute;
        top: 3px;
        pointer-events: none;
        left: 20px;
        transition: .5s;
      }
       .container .form-group input:focus ~label.name,
       .container .form-group input:valid ~label.name
      {
        left: 20px;
        top: -20px;
        color: rgb(66,133,244);
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

thanks for the help

Comment: I changed my example and did as I was advised. Anyway, the style is used wherever there is a "label". https://codepen.io/Smith37/pen/abOOLNZ
My new example https://codepen.io/Smith37/pen/XWbbqwr